# How to run a Spark jar file from AWS Console without Spark-Shell

Tags: amazon-web-services, jar, apache-spark, emr

I'm trying to run a Spark application on the AWS EMR Console (Amazon Web Services). My Scala script compiled in the jar takes the SparkConf settings as parameters or just strings:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("WikipediaGraphXPageRank")
  .setMaster(args(1))
  .set("spark.executor.memory","1g")
  .registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[PRVertex], classOf[PRMessage]))
```

However, I don't know how to pass the Master-URL parameter and other parameters to the jar when it's uploaded and I set-up the cluster. To be clear, I'm aware that if I was running the Spark-Shell I would do this another way, but I'm a Windows user and with the current set-up and work I've done, it would be very useful to have some way to pass the master URL to the EMR cluster in the 'steps'.

I don't want to use the Spark-Shell, I have a close deadline and have everything set-up this way and feels like just this small issue of passing the master URL as a parameter should be possible, considering that AWS have a guide for running stand-alone Spark applications on EMR.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you use spark-submit?

Comment: what is the type of your aws instance?

Comment: @Metropolis - have tried Spark-submit for sure!

Comment: @Elisiah - it's an EMR instance that I'm controlling through SHH.

Comment: @user3297367 do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here are instructions on using spark-submit via EMR Step: https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/examples/spark-submit-via-step.md